# Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS when using fetch to upload image on React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to upload an image to a server using fetch and it works fine on Android but on iOS I get an error, the upload actually works but this error always shows.

```js
export const uploadImage = async (image: Response, organisation: string, tokenData: any) => {
  if (image.data) {
    const JWT = pathOr('', ['getFileAccessToken', 'AccessToken'], tokenData);
    // image.filename doesn't exist on android
    const filename = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? image.filename : image.path.split('/').pop();
    const buffer = Buffer.from(image.data, 'base64');
    const response = await fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/files/${filename}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${JWT}`,
        'Content-Type': image.mime,
        'CP-Org-Name': organisation,
      },
      body: buffer,
    });
    return response.json();
  }
};
```